# Unicode Error when I try import a txt file tab separated

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

(I work on Mac)

When I insert my python code to obtain data from txt file (tab separated) I have the error: **"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4186: invalid start byte"**.

```
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori

def load_transactions (file_name, sep="\t"):  
    lines = open(file_name, 'rt').readlines()
    transactions_matrix = []
    for l in lines:
        l = l.rstrip('\n')
        transaction = l.split(sep)
        transactions_matrix.append(transaction)
    return transactions_matrix

groceries=load_transactions("Online_Retail.txt",sep="\t")

len(groceries)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You rely on UTF-8 as the default encoding, but It looks like the file isn't encoded in UTF-8. Specify the correct encoding in the `open` call.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this form:

1. First discover the unicode of the file

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector
usock = open('/Users/leonorbrites/Desktop/Online_Retail.txt', 'rb')
detector = UniversalDetector()
for line in usock.readlines():
    detector.feed(line)
    if detector.done: break
detector.close()
usock.close()
print (detector.result)
```

2. Then change the unicode from my file

```
def transactions (file_name, sep="\t"):  
    lines = open(file_name,'rt', encoding='iso-8859-1').readlines()
    transactions_matrix = []
    for l in lines:
        l = l.rstrip('\n')
        transaction = l.split(sep)
        transactions_matrix.append(transaction)
    return transactions_matrix

retail=transactions('/Users/leonorbrites/Desktop/Online_Retail.txt', sep="\t")

len(retail)
```